# What is the maximum number of columns a SQL table can have?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am using Laravel for my web application. I am migrating a table using `php artisan migrate`.

The table has 316 columns with 150 float columns and 150+ string columns

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Createtable_nameTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('column2');
            $table->foreign('column2')->references('column1')->on('table1')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('column3');
            $table->string('column4');
            $table->string('column5');
            $table->string('column6');
            $table->integer('column7')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('column8')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('column9')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('column10')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('column11')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('column12')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('column13')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('column14')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('column15')->unsigned();
            $table->float('column16');
            $table->float('column17');
            .
            .
            .
            .


            $table->float('column166');
            $table->string('column167');
           .
           .
           .
            $table->string('column316');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('table_name');
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large.-The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manualSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Why so much columns for a single table? Is every entry using them all? If not, look into json columns or redesign the db

Answer (score 3):

Last line of your question says you should check the manual, read this [Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html) and [row size limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html#row-size-limits)

> MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective
>   maximum may be less for a given table. The exact column limit depends
>   on several factors:
>
> The maximum row size for a table constrains the number (and possibly
>   size) of columns because the total length of all columns cannot exceed
>   this size. See Row Size Limits.
>
> The storage requirements of individual columns constrain the number of
>   columns that fit within a given maximum row size. Storage requirements
>   for some data types depend on factors such as storage engine, storage
>   format, and character set. See Data Type Storage Requirements.
>
> Storage engines may impose additional restrictions that limit table
>   column count. For example, InnoDB has a limit of 1017 columns per
>   table. See Limits on InnoDB Tables. For information about other
>   storage engines, see Alternative Storage Engines.
>
> Each table has an .frm file that contains the table definition. The
>   definition affects the content of this file in ways that may affect
>   the number of columns permitted in the table. See Section 12.6,
>   “Limits Imposed by .frm File Structure”.

So basically it depends on the storage engine, storage format and character set

Answer (score 0):

it's about how many bytes per row and not how many columns. The maximum number of columns varies depending on the column type since each type occupies a specific number of bytes.

I suggest you change your database model and have those columns as rows in a foreign table. You'll have a `table_name` and `table_name_columns` that references `table_name`.